# How Can I create a tab inside another tab in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabs

I need to do a tab inside another tab, When I touch a tab , Android need to open a new set of tabs. Can anyone help me?

I'm using this code: It works just to first set of tabs.

```
th = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
th.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

//coloca o formulario dentro da tab
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 1").setIndicator("Aba 1", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 2").setIndicator("Aba 2", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 3").setIndicator("Aba 3", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 4").setIndicator("Aba 4", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 5").setIndicator("Aba 5", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 6").setIndicator("Aba 6", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
th.addTab(
        th.newTabSpec("formulario 7").setIndicator("Aba 7", null),
        FragmentTab.class, null);
```

}

```
@Override
```

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

//pega a tag e compara com a string para inflar o xml
if (this.getTag() == "formulario 2") {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_json, container, false);
}
if(this.getTag() == "formulario 3"){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario3, container, false);
}
if(this.getTag() == "formulario 4"){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario2, container, false);
}
else return v;
```

}
}

Comment: Please add the code that you're using and be a little bit more specific about the problem you're having to get better help

Comment: That's really not very good UI design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested fragment tabs overlap on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339241/nested-fragment-tabs-overlap-on-android)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the API tutorials [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) Maybe something along those lines might help you find what you need. Cheers

Comment: @323go It depends on the complexity of the UI. I've seen it done cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you want your current tabs replaced by new ones as soon as the user clicks on an object inside one of your tab fragments. In that case you could

a) Create a new instance of your TabHost and fill it with your new tabs.

b) Simply open another fragment on top of your current fragment that contains the TabHost and just change the arguments for filling the TabHost.

I'd go with b) as it is more clean in my opinion at give your users the ability to go back and forth between your views without you having to handle the variables of the different TabHosts yourself.